# How to move/copy a file from one folder to other folder in android using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

In my application on button click i am able to download a file from url into my SDCARD of android whose path is something like **"mnt/sdcard/files/data.pdf"** and now i want to move/copy this file to some other destination folder using phonegap. Can anyone please help me how to do this in phonegap?

I have a pdf file in path **"mnt/sdcard/files/data.pdf"** and i want to move that pdf file to new path **"mnt/sdcard/download/data.pdf"** anyone please help me.

Comment: See: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/yA_TEb79FBg

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are actually using Cordova, check [FileEntry](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileEntry), which has methods named `moveTo` and `copyTo`.

Be aware that the file systems API are a callback hell.

One quick example from the docs cooked overlooking the docs:

```
var fail = function(err) { console.log(err) }
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///example.txt", function(file) {
   window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///directory-to-move-to", function(destination) {
             file.moveTo(destination,"example.txt");
   },fail)
},fail);
```

I skipped the error handling functions for clearness, suppose it works without it.

Comment: Hi i've tried to added ur code in this way as shown in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/janakipriya/Vkvsu/1/ is this right way?

Comment: Fixed yours: http://jsfiddle.net/Vkvsu/2/ and mine. There was one wrong extra arg. at the 2nd resolve. Though, be aware that it won't download a file, only move it. For downloading there is the file transfer object. Also, I am not very sure about the URLs, but i guess it's trial and error, it would help if you implemented the error handlers.

Comment: I have an prototype working for downloading and creating directories, but it's so so much more complicated. I will the error handling.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16687/discussion-between-pedrofurla-and-android-phonegap)